Remove root element from MessageHeader
My problem is that root element is written twice. I would like to delete root element generated by MessageHeader itself:
My code:
var el = XElement.Parse("<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext'>" +
        "<wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility'>" +
        "<wsse:Username>TEST</wsse:Username>" +
        "<wsse:Password Type='wsse:PasswordText'>TEST1</wsse:Password>" +
        "</wsse:UsernameToken>" +
        "</wsse:Security>");

request.Headers.Add(MessageHeader.CreateHeader("Security", "wsse", el));

Here, code generated in request header - I would like to remove outer 'Security' node, but I dont' know how:
<Security xmlns="wsse">
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext">
        <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility">
          <wsse:Username>TEST</wsse:Username>
          <wsse:Password Type="wsse:PasswordText">TEST1</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
    </Security>


Since there is no overload for MessageHeader.CreateHeader, you can just extract it from the parsed structure itself and use its data to create MessageHeader with it:
var el = XElement.Parse("<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext'>" +
        "<wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility'>" +
        "<wsse:Username>TEST</wsse:Username>" +
        "<wsse:Password Type='wsse:PasswordText'>TEST1</wsse:Password>" +
        "</wsse:UsernameToken>" +
        "</wsse:Security>");

string name = el.Name.LocalName;
string xmlns = el.Attributes().Single().Value;
XNode singleChild = el.Nodes().Single();

var h = MessageHeader.CreateHeader(name, xmlns, singleChild);

That should give you the desired result.
Note that MessageHeader.CreateHeader method forbids using names with ":" sign in it (so no NamespaceName are allowed).
Update based on comment
Alright, here is a way to replace what the MessageHeader outputs with a custom implementation of it:
public sealed class PrefixedMessageHeader(XElement header) : MessageHeader
{
    public override string Name => header.Name.LocalName;

    public override string Namespace => header.Name.Namespace.NamespaceName;

    protected override void OnWriteStartHeader(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion messageVersion)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement(header.GetPrefixOfNamespace(header.Name.Namespace), Name, Namespace);
    }

    protected override void OnWriteHeaderContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion messageVersion)
    {
        foreach (XNode node in header.Nodes())
        {
            using var reader = node.CreateReader();
            writer.WriteNode(reader, false);
        }
    }
}

So, instead of calling MessageHeader.CreateHeader you can just create initialize new PrefixedMessageHeader(el) and pass it on to the request.Headers.Add method.

One of my main problems is namespace as prefix. Maybe you know how can I achieve this? Root  is still without namespace.

@FrenkyB updated my answer to allow prefixes in the root element.

Thanks a lot. You really helped me solve big problem.

My complete solution - thanks to @AgentFire and this answer.
The only thing needed is add SecurityHeader class to Endpoint:
client.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new SecurityHeaderBehavior(username, password));

All classes:
public class UsernameToken
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class PrefixedMessageHeader : MessageHeader
{
    XElement header;
    public PrefixedMessageHeader(XElement headerInput)
    {
        header = headerInput;
    }

    public override string Name => header.Name.LocalName;

    public override string Namespace => header.Name.Namespace.NamespaceName;

    protected override void OnWriteStartHeader(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion messageVersion)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement(header.GetPrefixOfNamespace(header.Name.Namespace), Name, Namespace);
    }

    protected override void OnWriteHeaderContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion messageVersion)
    {
        foreach (XNode node in header.Nodes())
        {
            using (var reader = node.CreateReader())
            {
                writer.WriteNode(reader, false);
            }
        }
    }
}



public class SecurityHeader : MessageHeader
{
    public UsernameToken UsernameToken { get; set; }

    public override string Name => "Security";
    public override string Namespace => "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext";

    protected override void OnWriteHeaderContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion messageVersion)
    {
    }
}

public class StringXmlDataWriter : BodyWriter
{
    private string data;

    public StringXmlDataWriter(string data)
        : base(false)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    protected override void OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteRaw(data);
    }
}

public class SecurityHeaderInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    private static readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger("WS");

    private readonly string username;
    private readonly string password;

    public SecurityHeaderInspector(string username, string password)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        // No-op
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        XElement el = XElement.Parse("<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext'>" +
                    "<wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility'>" +
                    "<wsse:Username>TEST</wsse:Username>" +
                    "<wsse:Password Type='wsse:PasswordText'>TEST</wsse:Password>" +
                    "</wsse:UsernameToken>" +
                    "</wsse:Security>");

        request.Headers.Add(new PrefixedMessageHeader(el));
        _log.Info(request);
        return null;
    }
}

public class SecurityHeaderBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    private readonly string username;
    private readonly string password;

    public SecurityHeaderBehavior(string username, string password)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {

    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new SecurityHeaderInspector(this.username, this.password));
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {

    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {

    }
}

